# Проверить входящие данные $_POST в PHP

Tags: php, post

```
$amount = abs($_POST['amount']);
$md = intval($_POST['md']);
```

`$md` принимает цифровое значение и используется в коде для сравнения.

Правильно настроена фильтрация передаваемых данных?

Обошли следующую проверку:

```
if ($balance - $amount >= 0)
```

Значение $balance берётся из сессии пользователя.

```
$balance = $data['balance'];
```

Массив с данными пользователя:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
$sql = $pdo->Query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '".(int)$_SESSION['id']."'");
$data = $sql->Fetch();
$numq = $sql->RowCount();
$sess = (int)$_SESSION['id'];
$sess_login = $data['login'];
if($numq == 0) { session_start(); session_destroy(); }

}
```

Точно известно:

1. $amount и $md - передавалось как положительное число.
2. Сессия не была взломана.
3. Sql инъекция не использовалась.
4. $balance после обхода проверки изменилось на отрицательное число.

Comment: Можете также использовать механизмы filter в php: filter_var и прочие. Ваш вопрос немного не понятен, что вы хотите от пользователей здесь? То есть, в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Правильность установленных фильтров, остальное для ознакомления. Если в них ошибок нет, буду искать остальное самостоятельно или открою вопрос с другой темой. Буду благодарен за подробное объяснение использования filter в моём вопросе.

Comment: Понимаете, у вас нет настроенной фильтрации. Вы просто производите процесс преобразования и приведения к типам. По хорошему, если включить режим работы с ошибками, то все они будут сыпаться как `Error`, а это позволит через `try/catch` отловить и работать с ними.

Comment: Разве приведения к типам не есть фильтрация? Можете рассказать подробнее как в моём случае следует настроить фильтрацию или провести режим работы с ошибками?

Comment: Вы можете ознакомиться с практическими примерами и теорией на сайте официальной документации: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.filter.php

Comment: Отсутствие этих фильтров можно назвать уязвимостью?

Comment: и зачем нам тут знать про `md` если оно нигде не используется в приведенном коде? И что вообще следует из этого кода понять. Вот вы взяли одно число с одного места. другое другое. и сравнили их разницу с нулем. И какие мы отсюда выводы должны вам сказать? В этих отдельных фрагментах кода нет никакой общей логики, чтобы в чем то ошибку найти.

Comment: Прошу прощения, $md принимает цифровое значение и используется в коде для сравнения. Меня интересует фильтрация передаваемых двух переменных.

Comment: Фильтрация настроена правильно. Вопрос бессмысленный.

Comment: Ок, сменился у вас баланс на отрицательный, в проверках все "относительно" нормально, но откуда у вас эта дата появилась: `$data['balance'];`? 
При подобной проблеме - вопросе, дайте вырезки из кода с логикой, которая отрабатывает некорректно. В ином случае, все тыкают вам пальцем в небо..

Comment: Borislav, добавил массив с данными пользователя.